# Make a paragraph using array of textview android

Tags: android

```
String[] textArray={"one","two","three", "four", "five", "six"};

int length=textArray.length;

TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[length];
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);

for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
   textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);
   textViewArray[i].setText(textArray[i]);
   layout.addView(textViewArray[i]);
}
```

I need to do something like that.. so it would display as

one two three four
five six

It is not fix that only four words to display in a line, only want fit to screen and look like a paragraph. Please provide me suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append the string to textview and append space for each string added as below. You don't need array of textviews. Just append the strings to the same.

```
TextView tv= new TextView(MainActivtiy.this);
tv.setText(""); 
for(int i=0;i<textArray.length;i++)
{
    tv.append(textArray[i]);
    tv.append(" "); 
}
layout.addView(tv);
```

Edit:

```
TextView tv= new TextView(MainActivtiy.this);
tv.setText(""); 
for(int i=0;i<textArray.length;i++)
{
     SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(textArray[i]); 
     ss1.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(textArray[i]), 0, ss1.length(),  
     tv.append(ss1);
     tv.append(" "); 
}
layout.addView(tv);
```

MyClickableSpan Class

```
 class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan{   

String clicked;
    public MyClickableSpan(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
super();
clicked =string;    
}

public void onClick(View tv) {

   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,clicked ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //do what is required
}

public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
   ds.setColor(Color.BLUE);//set text color 
   //ds.setStrokeWidth(15f);
   ds.setUnderlineText(true); // set to false to remove underline
}
}
```

Comment: I can't do this because I have another functionality to tap on each and every textview and give action of that so. can you give me another solution

Comment: you can use a spannable string and set text with the spannable string

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved as follows

```
String text = "";
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    text += text + " " + textArray[i];
}

tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(text);
tv.setSingleLine(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();    
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    text.append(textArray[i]);
}

textViewArray = new TextView(this);
textViewArray.setText(text.toString().trim());
textViewArray.setSingleLine(false);
layout.addView(textViewArray);
```

Comment: for creating a single `TextView` there is no need to declare array of TextView's and unable to find the variable `i` on `textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);`

Comment: @SankarV: thanks for pointing it out. Both of them are my mistakes. I have edited them.

Comment: you still have the error unable to find the variable `i` at `textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);` because i is declared inside the `for` loop. change `textViewArray[i]` to `textViewArray`

Answer (score 0):

Declare a string object and keep appending array values to it and set value to textview once string is complete.

```
String para = "";
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
 para += textArray[i] + " ";
}
textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);
textViewArray[i].setText(para);
layout.addView(textViewArray[i]);
```

Comment: you don't need a textview array. you can use a single textview